# Loading From File Error In Java?

Tags: java, file, arraylist, objectinputstream, readfile

I have to implement Object Files for a java project, however I am having trouble when it comes to loading the file (Save is all OK)

```
public static void loadStudentList() {
    boolean endOfFile = false;

    try {
        // create a FileInputStream object, studentFile
        FileInputStream studentFile = new FileInputStream("Students.obf");
        // create am ObjectImnputStream object to wrap around studentStream
        ObjectInputStream studentStream = new ObjectInputStream(studentFile) ;

        // read the first (whole) object with the readObject method
        Student tempStudent = (Student) studentStream.readObject();
        while (endOfFile != true) {
            try {
                tempStudent = (Student) studentStream.readObject();
                stud1.add(tempStudent);
            }
            catch(EOFException e) {
                endOfFile = true;
            }
        }
        studentStream.close();
        //use the fact that the readObject throws an EOFException to check whether the end of eth file has been reached
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }

    catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {  // thrown by readObject
    /* which indicates that the object just read does not correspond to any class
known to the program */
        System.out.println("Trying to read an object of an unkonown class");
    }
    catch(StreamCorruptedException e) { //thrown by constructor
    // which indicates that the input stream given to it was not produced by an ObjectOutputStream object
        System.out.println("Unreadable File Format");
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("There was a problem reading the file");
    }
}
```

This is the code I used to load the files. The program will load **ONLY** the last 2 records in my file. The Idea is that I load all of them to an array list for future use in the program. Also I am not getting any of my catches back. Any help? Thanks :)

Comment: You are not storing the Student instance that is retrieved first (just before the while) in the stud1 collection. Could it be that the file only contains 3 records?

Comment: How many objects do you suppose to be loaded? Post the contents of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never add to the list the first Student that you read

```
Student tempStudent = (Student) studentStream.readObject();
         while (endOfFile != true)
        {
            try
            {

                 tempStudent = (Student) studentStream.readObject();
                 stud1.add(tempStudent);
            }
```

Remove the read before the while, like the code below

```
     while (endOfFile != true)
    {
        try
        {

             Student tempStudent = (Student) studentStream.readObject();
             stud1.add(tempStudent);
        }
```

I am not sure if this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add the objects to an `ArrayList<Type>` then write/serialize them to file
and then for reading/deserialize it, read the data into one `ArrayList<Type>`.

Then you could fetch your objects one by one from the ArrayList

This might be an easier trouble free way of doing it.

```
  //Serialize
  ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
  //Add the student objects to the array list
  File f = new File("FileName.ser");
  ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
  objOut.writeObject(students);

   //Deserialize
   ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
   ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("FileName.ser")));
   students = (ArrayList<String>) objIn.readObject();
```

Comment: i am doing that , using the .add method for each object in the file